# how to disable the dropdown based on another dropdown selected value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
<tr>
    <td class="einput">Admission Type :</td>
    <td class="einput">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Adm_Type_LSeq, (SelectList)ViewBag.lstAdmType, String.Empty, new { @class = "drpclass" })
    </td>
    <td class="einput">Hostel Name :</td>
    <td class="einput">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hostel_Seq, (SelectList)ViewBag.lstHostel, String.Empty, new { @class = "drpclass" })
    </td>
</tr>.
```

this is my code in html5 ...in this admission type have two values "hosteller" and "dayscholar" when i select admission type as dayscholar, hostel name dropdown should be disable then i select admission type as a hosteller hostel name dropdown should be enable. 
this only my requirement ..please help me some one..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       if ($("#Select1").val() == "dayscholar") 
        {
          $("#Select2").attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else
        {
          $("#Select2").removeAttr('disabled');
        }


         $("#Select1").change(function () {

         if ($(this).val() == "dayscholar") 
         {

          $("#Select2").attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
             else
             {
              $("#Select2").removeAttr('disabled');
             }
         });
    });
```

cshtml code :

```
 <tr>
                        <td class="einput">Admission Type :
                        </td>
                        <td class="einput">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Adm_Type_LSeq, (SelectList)ViewBag.lstAdmType, String.Empty, new { @class = "drpclass" ,@id="Select1" })
                        </td>
                        <td class="einput">Hostel Name :
                        </td>
                        <td class="einput">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hostel_Seq, (SelectList)ViewBag.lstHostel, String.Empty, new { @class = "drpclass",@id="Select2" })
                        </td>
               </tr>
```

**Demo :**  http://jsfiddle.net/Vx7H8/

Comment: its worked correctly Amit.but in my case not only change function... because i used the above cshtml page as edit page in my form so when ever the admission type as dayscholar it should be disable the hostel name so please give more on this.....

Comment: check it now i made changes to the jquery